# Unable to create Webhook Subscription for Event-Grid

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid

I'm having this issue with Azure Event-Grid since yesterday and cannot find where I'm doing wrong.

I've used the below link to create a custom event-grid topic in azure cli. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/scripts/event-grid-cli-create-custom-topic

And used the link below to handle validation at the endpoint side.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/receive-events

and testing with the following payload

```
[{
"subject": "Contoso/foo/bar/items",
"eventType": "Microsoft.EventGrid.SubscriptionValidationEvent",
"eventTime": "2017-08-16T01:57:26.005121Z",
"id": "602a88ef-0001-00e6-1233-1646070610ea",
"data": { 
        "validationCode": "123456789"
        },
"dataVersion": "",
"metadataVersion": "1"
}]
```

and getting 123456789 back with a 200 response.

When I run the commands at the link below, I'm getting this error.

> Deployment failed. Correlation ID:
>   6acbe8ab-1bf5-4f35-b133-9c907c2e2545. The operation failed due to an
>   internal server error. The initial state of the impacted resources (if
>   any) are restored. Please try again in few minutes. If error still
>   persists, report 05a94a7a-b132-451b-90ff-ceb2f5d587ae:6/3/2020 3:49:40
>   PM (UTC) to our forums for assistance or raise a support ticket .

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/scripts/event-grid-cli-subscribe-custom-topic

Much thanks in advance

Comment: btw, azure forums doesn't have event-grid topic which is mandatory to ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am missing the implementation of your validation handshake (in your webhook implementation), but if you have just returned the "123456789" in your HTTP-200 response, that might be the reason.

You have to return a json payload, containing your code, like the following:

```
{
  "validationResponse": "123456789"
}
```

More detailed explanation in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/receive-events).

Comment: you can easily look at the code we have in our arcus-eventgrid package, open sourced on github: https://github.com/arcus-azure/arcus.eventgrid/blob/master/src/Arcus.EventGrid.Security/EventGridSubscriptionValidator.cs.  you can also just add it to your webapi project (nuget package) and just tag your ApiOperation with the attribute and you're set